# Building AngularJS UI for MYSQL DB. Attempting to add column that displays total from another table

Tags: mysql, angularjs

Currently, I have two tables: Assets and Invoices. I can have multiple invoices corresponding to a single asset, each with their own monetary value. I need to add a column to the Asset table that will display the total value of all invoices for each asset.

For example, if I have my Invoices table as such:

InvoiceID | AssetID | Value

1..................100..........15.00

2..................100..........10.00

3..................101...........5.00

I need my Assets table to display:

AssetID | TotalValue

100............25.00

101............5.00

Is what I'm asking for even possible in MySQL? If so, what would be the path of least resistance for completing it? I know I could write a simple query for each individual asset, but I'm attempting to make a UI that will display the current TotalValue for each individual Asset all at once.

Any help at all would greatly be appreciated. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything. Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no "right" approach, I believe a more "normalized" approach would be to compute the TotalValue on each query you make to the database.

I'm unaware as to what you're using for your backend/database interactions but if you're writing SQL queries, a query using GROUP BY() and SUM() should do the trick. Checkout this for more info here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Performing this operation at the query level instead of storing it in the table may generally be seen as "better" practice because an aggregated/sum column is data that can be derived from other data within the same table meaning double-storing data (just in a different format!). (Quick read on normalization http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/abhijit_desai/2010/09/07/noramlization/

It also keeps your database a little more flexible. If you were to hard-store the total values in the database, should you ever need to go back and update/delete an invoice's value, you'd need to also re-compute and update each database record that is associated with the Asset that invoice touches.

Hope this helps and hope I was clear enough! Let me know if I wasn't clear in anyway!